# 1/0 should be output as true/false in MySQL and Postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench, postman

I have a column named `snapshot_push` which have the data type `tinyint(1)` in a table named `app_user_has_views` in MySQL.

When I insert values I use `true/false` but it is inserted as `1/0`. That is due to the `tinyint(1)` datatype I know.

When I use `SELECT snapshot_push from app_user_has_views` it output as `1/0`

When I use `SELECT IF(snapshot_push = 1, 'true', 'false') as snapshot_push FROM app_user_has_views` it produces `true/ false` in *MySQL Workbench*.

But in *Postman* it shows 'true/false' as string because I have used `'true', 'false'` in the above mentioned query. I am using `mysql-promise` and `Node JS` for connecting the database.
I just want to know if there is any other way to show it `true/false` as *values* in both *Postman* and *MySQL Workbench* ?